# Database description in app.config organization

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have project which consist of couple of assemblies.

- `Project.Entities` is class library with entities and database descriptions (I am using EF6 + SqlServer Compact Edition 4)
- `Project.Core` is also class library and contains entire business logic (depends upon `Project.Entities`)
- `Project.UI` is WPF application which contains UI declaration and couple of translators from entities (declared in `Project.Entities`) to WPF-suitable view models.

Now I faced following issue: I want to keep entire information about database in app.config which presented in `Project.Entities`. But upon start I got an error that connection string not found or provider not found end blah-blah-blah. Finally only one way can solve it - move all sections (`entityFramework`, `connectionStrings`, `system.data`) to `app.config` of `Project.UI`.

UPD: My `packages.config` for `Project.Entities` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Should I also add the same packages to UI project to start it? Or I can keep all database-related features in Entities assembly?

I am not sure whther it is correct or not, I an very new in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you must have a single config file per `AppDomain`. So you need to add all entity framework specific parts of the config from your `Project.Entities` including the connectionstring to your App.Config of the `Project.UI` assembly.

Actually all settings that you need within your `AppDomain` must be in this config file.

This isn't WPF specific, it works for all CLR runned executable, services, websites, etc.

A detailed descibtion can found be [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/06/02/app-config-files.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I thought that during build all app.configs merged or each app.config embedded into parent's assembly.